# OLEDB source- sql command is not allowing long query

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, msbi

i have so many lines of query , OLEDB source -sql command is not allowing to enter all the  query , is there any alternative....??

Comment: Your description of the problem is vague.  Is the input simply too long to be submitted on the command line?  I doubt that it's too long to be placed into a file and digested.  Break it up logically.  Take SELECTions with lots of conditions and orderings and such and recast them as DEFINE VIEW statements.  Execute those first.  Then execute the queries that can be transacted against those views.

Comment: @BruceDavidWilner all those views mentioned could definitely tank performance!  But Anil you really should really post a bit more detail such as the exact error message.  Is your query longer than 8,000 characters which is the max? If so you could also start eliminating whitespace....Also you could store it in a file or databse and populate a variable to see if you could get around the 8000 character limit

Comment: Just adding to what Matt has said, the other option you have is creating a procedure in the source and have it called.

Comment: Or create a view in SQL Server and use that as Source statement

Comment: Hello all thanks for your valued response ....  i don't have access to create Store Procedure, and yes my query is more than 8000 characters ... it s too long ------  is there any process like we plase query into file and process that file through SSIS ... ??

Comment: You can use a script component as source. I haven't worked with it , but it is possible https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136018.aspx

Comment: you might be able to place the whole query in a flat file.  use a flat file connection to load the data into a variable using a dataflow task and then use that variable in the source definition you need.  Of as @DenStudent pointed out you can use a Script Component in your data flow task as a source.  Or you could work on splitting your query into parts and using multiple sources with JOIN/Union etc to reproduce what you want.  Or my #1 guess if the query is that long there are multiple operations being done such as populating temp tables, etc. so break those out to steps in your data flow.

Comment: Also 8000 characters is really really long for a query.  eliminating white space and using table aliases and a few other things can probably reduce the length greatly

Comment: Matt, people are far too quick to point out what would or would not deleteriously affect performance.  According to the complainant, HIS QUERY DOES NOT RUN AT ALL.  So much for performance!!

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to save your query locally as .sql file. Choose browse button inside the OLEDB component, then choose the saved file... It works for me. :)